# Rails join from association in two tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, associations

I have to tables: Associates and Departments

One associate belongs to a department (belongs_to) and one department has many associates (has_many)

What I', trying to do is count number of associates on each department and make a pie chart with the data, i got the chart working with something basic (Department.count)

I just started with rails and I'm having issues with the query

```
Associate.joins(:department).group(:name).count
```

what i get is the following

> Mysql2::Error: Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, name AS name FROM `associates` INNER JOIN `departments` ON `departments`.`id` = `associates`.`department_id` GROUP BY name

I tried doing a select, find and I just cant seem to get it right

Comment: use the name of the table in the group clause: `group('associates.name')`

Comment: Worked like a charm!! I should of thought of that, but since i was already doing a join in department i didn't think it would be necessary! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you have your associations setup correctly, I believe you should be able to do something like this:

```
Department.find(<some_id>).associates.count
```

Or if you have all the departments, and you're looping through them, let's say in a view and you want to get all the counts, you can do something like this:

```
@departments = Deparment.all

@departments.each do |department|
  department.associates.count
end
```

You're associate table will need a `department_id` column on it.

Comment: This is not optimized code, you should let the DB deals with the counting process.

Comment: I did this and it did work it pulls out the count of the two different two departments in the database but i want to be able to display it in my chart like this 
    = pie_chart Department.joins(:associates).group(:department => :name).count

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment on your post, you have to resolve the ambiguous `name` attributed by specifying the table.  You can do so either with the string as suggested, or by passing a block to `group_by`:

`Associate.joins(:department).group_by(&:name).count`